# Can Performance Testing possible in a Partial Copy sandbox?

Tags: performance, test-automation

Salesforce suggests Performance Testing only in Full Copy sandbox. Is there any reason why it cant be done in a Partial Copy sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Partial Copy sandboxes have only subset of the production data and are limited by storage limit. Check out this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=5). Most teams use partial copy sandboxes to validate their day to day code developments, bug fixes and integration scenarios. Due to the lack of complete data, you can't really use it for performance testing *[Ideally, performance testing is done on a full copy sandbox that will be used for testing in the last stage before production deployment]*. That being said, if your total production data is less than total storage limit of the partial copy sandbox, there is nothing stopping you from doing performance testing on this sandbox.